# Rmarkdown: is it possible to get a nice verbatim code in ioslides?

Tags: r, markdown, rstudio, r-markdown

I am using `Rmarkdown` and `ioslides`.

I would like to get this nice text with gray background and monospace font that I can get on stackoverflow when one embeds text within ``

Unfortunately, when I use this syntax in my ioslides, my text appears more like **verbatim code** than `verbatim code`.

Text enclosed within `` renders correctly when the output is `html`, but does not seem to work with `ioslides`

Example

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: ioslides_presentation
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## R Markdown

Here is the problem, fella: I want some nice `verbatim code`
````

gives

[image]

where is my nice background and my nice font?

Is there anything one can do here? Maybe playing with the `css`?
Thanks!

Comment: can you show an example please? Do you mean precisely that you want text in monospace font on a gray background box?

Comment: well the example described already. Yes, I want gray background with monospace font. like `ben bolker is the man`

Comment: guys calm down on the closing vote. verbatim code is the name used on the rmarkdown cheat sheet https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/rmarkdown-cheatsheet-2.0.pdf. how do you want me to call that?

Comment: I think the close-voters are requesting a more explicit example. Can you embed a minimal .Rmd file as a code block, and perhaps an image of the rendered HTML? I know you think your example is clear and sufficient, but clarity and sufficiency are often in the eye of the beholders - *you* know exactly what you mean, but maybe we don't ...

Comment: also, you don't really have to worry about close votes at all until they reach the closure point. *If* the question is closed, then you can worry about how to edit the question to address the issues raised by the close-voters ...

Comment: updated everything my man

Comment: You could at least use `theme: default`. Interestingly that adds the grey backgrounds.

Comment: incredible... thanks @MartinSchmelzer. Maybe that can help pinpoint what is the correct `css`?